# Why is my new high efficiency furnace blowing cold air sometimes?

Tags: furnace

Why does my new furnace high efficient Payne furnace blow cold air,not constantly but at least 3 different times in a day, my thermastat is set on auto but when the weather is cold outside it will still blow  cold air thru out the house how do I turn this off ,is there an option ? Or do I need to buy a new thermastat that has an off switch for the fan instead of what I have  an / on/auto switch Only

Comment: Is it a heat pump or does the system include an air conditioner?  Are you located in "heating season" or "cooling season"?  What kind of thermostat is it?

Comment: You're going to have to read the owners manual of both the furnace, and the thermostat to determine what options are available and how to turn them on/off.  If you want help from us, you'll have to tell us the make and model of both the furnace and thermostat. Does the air start out cool and then warm up, or are the cool air cycles in addition to the warm air cycles (for example does it blow cold air 3 times a day, and warm air 7 times a day)?

Comment: You might be able to adjust the fan for these periods when the furnace wants to circulate unheated air.  If so, set the fan to a lower speed and you will not notice it at all, or not as much.

Comment: It actually might not be *cold* cold air. If it's circulating air that's only 80 degrees F or something like that, it might not *feel* warm if you put your hand in it, but it's warmer than outside and still warming your house. I have a high efficiency furnace that does this every few cycles. My father has a heat pump that does this constantly.

Comment: Voting to close. Still no details about the system.

Answer (score 2):

If it's blowing cold air right after it fires up, it's just the cold air that's already inside the ducts, kind of like cold water in your hot water pipes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar furnace. I am going to assume that this is the normal cycling, throughout the day, where the controller is giving air movement throughout the house for comfort reasons. It's controlled by a variable speed motor on the fan by your thermostat, I think.

If the air is too cold, you should talk to your installer and ask them about that. I recall that sometimes the air did feel a touch cool (in my former home) but it's been a while. I just wasn't used to the circulation and wound up setting my temperature a degree warmer than usual.

Answer (score 0):

The humidifier may be telling it to blow. The thermostat may do it to sample the air or the furnace may have a 'stir' setting.

Answer (score 0):

Auto is off. Auto Makes fan come on with call of heat or cool. Check to see if you have a air circulation timer mounted on your furnace.